# BigQuery Solana dataset is incorrect/incomplete

Tags: data

We have noticed the data in the Solana dataset on BQ is incomplete.

Consider this wallet:
https://solscan.io/account/9GG2JGrrLjNYN3nUBdFtCeG3R4QViShMDgKGAgrWkJJf

As you can see, there was a transfer of 18.55 SOL from Binance2 on the 30th November (long enough to update by now):

https://solscan.io/tx/3GDn817MYC2qix16ZfKveNNxud1vWkAWh1TeSfq9nZVNt6Ufws55Z238d7qUpDaHm7c841sqgJjkv4mko1t3KugK

This does appear in BigQuery as a Token_Transfer, but with a null value:
[image: This does appear in BigQuery as a Token_Transfer, but with a null value:]

And so it does not update the Accounts table, where it doesn't show at all:
[image: And so it does not update the Accounts table, where it doesn't show at all]

We believe there is some error in processing somewhere and this is very worrying. We want to use this dataset but it's useless if we can't trust it.

Who can we talk to? Who is in charge of this?

Thanks in advance!